# "post" method condition not working in django form edit and save

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-forms

After Clicking on a edit method in a form the data of the model gets loaded in the form view but when I click on the save button the value is not saved instead the page is again reloaded with the same values. Saving the New form in database via form works fine

views.py

```
def sessioncreate(request):
if request.method=="GET":
    form=SessionForm();
    return  render(request,'app/sessions_form.html',{'form':form});
elif request.method=="POST":
    form=SessionForm(request.POST);
    form.save();
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/sessions');


def SessionUpdate(request,pk):
    post = get_object_or_404(Sessions, pk=pk)
    if request.method == "post":
        form = SessionForm(request.POST)
        form.save()
        return RedirectView('/sessions',pk=form.pk);
    else:
        form = SessionForm(instance=post)


return  render(request,'app/sessions_form.html',{'form':form});
```

models.py

```
class Sessions(models.Model):
    title=models.CharField(max_length=50)
    abstract=models.CharField(max_length=2000)
    track=models.ForeignKey(Track)
    speaker=models.ForeignKey(Speaker)
    status=models.CharField(max_length =1, choices=SESSION_STATUSES)
 # returning name in site 
def __str__(self):
    return self.title
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse('sessions_detail', kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

class SessionForm(forms.ModelForm):
   class Meta:
       model=Sessions;
       fields=['title','abstract','track','speaker'];
```

url.py

```
    url(r'^sessions/$',views.SessionList.as_view(),name='sessions_list'),
url(r'^sessions/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.SessionDetail.as_view() ,   name='sessions_details'),

url(r'^sessions/create/$',views.sessioncreate, name='sessions_create'),
url(r'^sessions/update/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.SessionUpdate , name='sessions_update'),
url(r'^sessions/delete/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$',views.SessionDelete.as_view() , name='sessions_delete'),
```

session_form.html

```
{% extends 'layout.html' %}



{% block content %}
<form method="post">
    {% csrf_token%}
    {{form.as_table}}
      <button type="submit">Save</button>

</form>

{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was my final views.py update file which worked...anything redundant i can remove from that ?

```
def SessionUpdate(request,pk):
form_class=SessionForm
post = get_object_or_404(Sessions, pk=pk)
form = SessionForm(request.POST)
if request.method == "POST":
    if form.is_valid():
        form = SessionForm(request.POST, instance=post)
        form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/sessions')
else:
    form = SessionForm(instance=post)


return  render(request,'app/sessions_form.html',{'form':form});
```

Answer (score 1):

Methods are all caps. You should check `if request.method == 'POST'`.

Note also that you never check that your form is valid; you should do so by calling `if form.is_valid()` before the save.